# Divs appears inside a brother div, not inside his parent

Tags: html, nested

Im working on a wordpress page, want to display the content of posts in a specific layout, it work well, but when I add another post, the posts "dos" and "tres", appears inside the post "uno", instead of on his real parent the "nested" div. any clues?

```
<div class="grid">
   <div class="post principal"> 
      <!--show data-->
   </div>
   <div class="nested">
      <?php if($count_post>1){?> <!--if there is more post fill div with data-->
      <div class="post uno">
        <!--show data-->
      </div>
      <?php }else{?>
      <div class="post uno">
        <!--dont show anything but keep the div-->
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if($count_post>2){?>
      <div class="post dos">
         <!--show data-->
      </div>
      <?php }else{?>
      <div class="post dos">
         <!--dont show anything but keep the div-->
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if($count_post>3){?>
      <div class="post tres">
         <!--show data-->
      </div>
      <?php }else{?>
      <div class="post tres">
        <!--dont show anything but keep the div-->
      </div>
      <?php } ?>        
   </div> <!--end nested-->
</div> <!--end grid-->
```

here it is all the code, the wierd thing is that lets say I have two posts in the array and all is correctly displayed, but when I add another the post "dos" and "tres" changes parent

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=7' );?>
<!--Obtener la cantidad de post-->
<?php $count_post = $the_query->post_count;?>

<div class="grid">
    <div class="post principal">
        <!--Obtener la id del post-->
        <?php $post_id = $the_query->posts[0]->ID;?>
        <!--Obtener la id de la imagen-->
        <?php $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);?>
        <!--Obtener source de la imagen-->
        <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'full');?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($the_query->posts[0]);?>"><img id="img_prin" src="<?php echo $img[0] ?>" alt=""></a>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($the_query->posts[0]);?>">
            <h2>
                <?php echo $the_query->posts[0]->post_name;?>
            </h2>
        </a>
        <?php $content = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);?>
        <p>
            <?php echo $content;?>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="nested">
    <?php if($count_post>1){?>      

            <div class="post uno">
                <?php $post_id1 = $the_query->posts[1]->ID;?>
                <?php $thumbnail_id1 = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id1);?>
                <div class="img_post">
                    <?php $img1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id1);?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $img1[0] ?>" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="cont">
                    <h5>
                        <?php echo $the_query->posts[1]->post_name;?>
                    </h5>
                    <?php $full_post1 = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id1);?>
                    <?php echo $excerpt1 = substr($full_post1,0,50).'...';?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }else{?>
            <div class="post uno"><div class="img_post"></div><div class="cont"></div>
         </div><?php } ?> 
        <?php if($count_post>2){?>

            <div class="post dos">
                <?php $post_id2 = $the_query->posts[2]->ID;?>
                <?php $thumbnail_id2 = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id2);?>
                <?php $img2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id2); >
                <div class="img_post">
                     <img src="<?php echo $img2[0] ?>" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="cont">
                    <h5>
                        <?php echo $the_query->posts[2]->post_name;?>
                    </h5>
                    <?php $full_post2 = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id2);?>
                    <?php echo $excerpt2 = substr($full_post2,0,50).'...';?> <!--EXCERPT-->
                </div>

            </div>
        <?php }else{?>
            <div class="post dos"><div class="img_post"></div><div class="cont"></div>
        </div><?php } ?> 
        <?php if($count_post>3){?>

            <div class="post tres">
                <?php $post_id3 = $the_query->posts[3]->ID;?>
                <?php $thumbnail_id3 = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id3);?>
                <?php $img3 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id3);>
                <div class="img_post">
                    <img src="<?php echo $img3[0] ?>" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="cont">
                    <h5>
                        <?php echo $the_query->posts[3]->post_name;?>
                    </h5>
                    <?php $full_post3 = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id3);?>
                    <?php echo $excerpt3 = substr($full_post3,0,50).'...';?> 

                 </div>

            </div>
       <?php }else{?>
            <div class="post tres"><div class="img_post"></div><div  class="cont"></div>
        </div><?php } ?>
     </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It may be because you are missing the closing bracket on the `else` clause for `$count_post>3`? As far as I can see, that might be the only thing causing it.

Comment: Sorry, just a typo

Comment: Could you possibly add more code before/after this section? Because `the posts "dos" and "tres", appears inside the post "uno"` absolutely should not be happening in this scenario. Every div is being closed correctly. I reckon inside one of your `<!--show data-->` sections you will have an unclosed `div` element.

Comment: I triple cheked, if that was the error, it wouldnt work a first, but it does, just when y add another post, the "post uno" asumes the parenthood of "dos" y "tres."